# hibernate HQL - subquery

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple (I guess) problem but I have no idea what's wrong.
I'm trying to execute following HQL query:

```
String hql = "delete CinemaProgramme program where program.id in (select q.id from CinemaProgramme q left join q.timetable a " +
                       "where a > :today)";
```

and I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: References to collections must be define a SQL alias

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: References to collections must be define a SQL alias
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.ElementPropertyMapping.toColumns(ElementPropertyMapping.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.toColumns(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1541)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getIdentityColumn(FromElement.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolveAsAlias(IdentNode.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolve(IdentNode.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4834)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3992)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4696)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.inRhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4596)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.deleteStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at movies.database.CinemaListDao.deleteOldData(CinemaListDao.java:97)
    at movies.controller.MovieController.viewRegistration(MovieController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at movies.encoding.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:14)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However, when I just try to execute the  query without the delete:

```
String hql = "from CinemaProgramme program where program.id in (select q.id from CinemaProgramme q left join q.timetable a " +
                       "where a > :today)";
```

Then it works fine....

Subquery itself also works correctly:

```
 String hql  = "select q.id from CinemaProgramme q left join q.timetable a " +
                           "where a > :today)"
```

........

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cinema_programme")
public class CinemaProgramme implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "programme_id")
    private List<Date> timetable;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;
}
```

Any ideas?

PS.
delete from CinemaProgramme AS program  - also doesn't work

Comment: This statement `delete CinemaProgramme program where program.id in (...);` appears to be wonky. Didn't you forget to add the `FROM` clause in this statement - `delete from CinemaProgramme program where program.id in (...);`.

Comment: Someone told me that that I shouldn't use FROM in DELETE in hql so I removed it. But still, with or without the FROM the same exception is thrown.

Comment: If you see a complete exception stack-trace on the server log, please append it to the question body. It may be helpful in bringing some answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details about the entities. Does this work:

*delete CinemaProgramme where id in (select q.id from CinemaProgramme q left join q.timetable a where a > :today)*

OR

*delete CinemaProgramme where timetable > :today*

Comment: I updated the question and no - they also doesn't work .